# Nokogiri gem installation error with spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

I'm getting this error when I try to bundle install

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/theareba/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/nokogiri-1.6.1.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried removing nokogiri in the cache and bundle installing again in vain.
Here's my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
ruby "2.0.0"

gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-1-stable'
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-1-stable'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'

gem 'sass-rails' 
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'turn', :require => false 
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'taps', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

**UPDATE**
Error that occurs when I run gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.0'

```
Fetching: mini_portile-0.5.2.gem (100%)
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Note: I've installed both `libxslt1-dev` and `libxml2-dev` that are requirements in nokogiri installation. 
I've also tried `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'` but it still fails. I've installed nokogiri -v 1.5.0 in another app so I tried it in this app and got the error that spree requires nokogiri version 1.6.0 or greater. I'm I missing something?

Comment: please put error trace on `gem install nokogiri` command

Comment: and add `mkmf.log` also

Comment: @Monk_Code I've added the error trace on gem install nokogiri.

Comment: @majioa how do I find mkmf.log?

Comment: you have not mkmf installed... strangely...

Comment: issue in bash: `$ irb` and then in the irb: `require 'mkmf'`

Comment: if you get `false` or exception, reinstall ruby itself, because ruby std-lib hasn't  properly installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here's what solved my problem. I created a new gemset i.e

```
rvm gemset create nokogiri
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353@nokogiri
```

Note: I'm using rvm and ruby 2.0.0. Then I made sure I've got necessary lib installed by running

```
sudo apt-get install  libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

The libraries happened to be already installed. Then I installed nokogiri

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
```

It installed  successfully. And finally ran `bundle install` to get all my gems. Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.

Comment: I am running into a very similar problem with ruby 2.0.0-p353 which remains unsolved.  Interestingly, I can successfully install nokogiri using Ruby 2.0.0-p195.  Please see my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983515/problems-installing-nokogiri-gem-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard-with-ruby-2-0-0-p353

Comment: On centOS I had problems with nokogiri compiling libxml2, Note that you can install a packaged version of `libxml2` and then use it to build the gem: `sudo apt-get install libxml2; gem install nokigiri -- --use-system-libraries`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the RVM gemset. I fixed it by restoring the gemset.  If you try upgrading to 4.0.2? I used Nokogiri 1.6.1 with Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.2

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

and reinstall `nokogiri`

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```